# Js как удалить только что созданный элемент при нажатии на него

Tags: javascript

```js
function addText (col){
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = col;
  ul1.appendChild(elem);
}

function deleteText (col){
  elem.remove; //жалкая попытка
}

but.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let nothing = addText(col.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text"id="col">
<button id="but">я кнопка</button>
<ul id="ul1"></ul>
```

Задание было такое - есть кнопка, поле ввода и <.ul.>. Надо сделать

1. написанное в поле добавлялось в <.ul.> на клик
2. contextmenu не работало
3. при нажатии правым кликом на элемент в списке он удалялся

Я сделал первые два, но я вообще не понимаю как сделать третье, подскажите способ как можно удалить элемент на клик

Comment: После добавления элемента можно повесить слушатель на удаление по клику 
  elem.addEventListener('contextmenu',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ul1.removeChild(this);
   })

Comment: @Алексей , там может быть три элемента,и при нажатии на один должен удаляться именно тот,на который нажали(в этом в основном вся загвоздка). То что вы написали не работает потому что оно не понимает что такое elem :(

Comment: let elem = document.createElement('div'); после этой строчки если добавить слушателя, элементы удаляются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('but');
const col = document.getElementById('col');
const ul1 = document.getElementById('ul1');

// функция создания элемента списка
const makeListItem = (content) => {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  el.textContent = content;
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', deleteSelf);
  return el;
};

// удаляем элемент по клику, если клавиша - правая кнопка
const deleteSelf = (ev) => {
  if (ev.which === 3) {
    ev.target.remove();
  }
};

// создаем элемент и добавляем в список
const addText = (col) => {
  const elem = makeListItem(col);
  ul1.append(elem);
};

// добавляем элемент и сбрасываем значение
but.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addText(col.value);
  col.value = '';
});

// отключение контекстного меню
ul1.addEventListener('contextmenu', (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

// отключение выделения, которое тоже вызывает контекстное меню
ul1.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="col" />
<button id="but">я кнопка</button>
<ul id="ul1"></ul>
```

Comment: несколько вопросов 1) "el.addEventListener('mousedown', deleteSelf);" почему оно внутри функции? Функция вызывается только при нажатии на кнопку, почему оно работает вообще?  2)я протестил, почему появляются маркера списка?

Comment: 1. Это коллбек функция. addEventListener является функцией высшего порядка. Например, в функцию const foo = (callback) => { callback() }; если мы передадим deleteSelf, то она будет вызвана в теле. А сама переданная функция может иметь какую угодно структуру. Можно не выделять в отдельную функцию и передать её анонимно () -> deleteSelf(), это будет тем же самым. 2. Маркера убираются с помощью css: задайте ul { list-style-type: none; } https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428570/

Comment: по первому пункту: addEventListener навешивает слушатель на кнопку, она не вызывается по нажатию. Почитайте про события здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addText (col){
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = col;
  elem.addEventListener('click', deleteText);
  ul1.appendChild(elem);
}

function deleteText(){
  this.remove();
}

but.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  addText(col.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text"id="col">
<button id="but">я кнопка</button>
<ul id="ul1"></ul>
```